# how to access method in nested class from main - C#

Tags: c#, list, nested-class

this is editing of my first question:
so i checked the assignment again.
all code is working as my professor want it to work, but only my question that i asked before is my problem. - how can i execute the method ShowGrade directly from the list (which is course) like:  list[1].ShowGrade(0) without using list[1].s.ShowGrade(0) ??
i will put here all my code.
the two console lines in the Main is what he want (and how he wants it), my constraints for the assignment were:
1. nested class Student in class Course (one student for course).
2. no constructors at all but the default constructors.
3. the ShowGrade method won't be in the Course class.
4. no operator . (dot) in ShowGrade, only []
5. in method Q1 will be only one query.

so my code is:

course. cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace HW_1
{
    public class Course 
    {
        private delegate int Del(Course c);

        internal string courseName { get; set; }

        public  class Student
        {
            internal string stuName { get; set; }
            internal List<int> gradesList { get; set; }

            //internal int ShowGrade(int index)
            //{
            //    return gradesList[index];
            //}
        }

        internal Student s = new Student();

        public override string ToString()
        {
            string gr = null;
            foreach (var g in s.gradesList)
                gr += g + " ";
            return string.Format("{0, -6} {1, -14} {2, -10}", courseName, s.stuName, gr);
        }

    }
}
```

Program.cs :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace HW_1
{
    class Program
    {
        private delegate bool Del(Course c);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Course> list = new List<Course>
            { 
                new Course {courseName = "C#", s = new Course.Student {stuName = "Jojo", gradesList = new List<int>(){10, 20, 100}}},
                new Course {courseName = "C", s = new Course.Student {stuName = "Bambi", gradesList = new List<int>(){99}}},
                new Course {courseName = "Java", s = new Course.Student {stuName = "Bambi", gradesList = new List<int>(){}}}

            };

            Console.WriteLine("List of courses:");
            Print(list);

            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Press P / p for students who passed in average 60 and those who didn't.");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Press # for C# courses and others.");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Press any other key for courses with student who have at least one grade of 100 and all oter courses.");

            char ch = (char)Console.Read();
            Del d = ((ch == 'P' || ch == 'p') ? (Del)(c => c.s.gradesList.Count > 0 && c.s.gradesList.Average() >= 60) : ((ch == '#') ? (Del)(c => c.courseName == "C#") : (Del)(c => c.s.gradesList.Contains(100))));

            var x = Q1 <IGrouping<bool, Course>>(list, d);
            Print(x);

            Console.WriteLine("");
            //Console.WriteLine(list[1].ShowGrade(0));
            //Console.WriteLine(list[2].ShowGrade(3));

        }

        static IEnumerable<T> Q1<T>(IEnumerable<Course> list, Del d)
        {
            var query =
                from c in list
                orderby d(c)
                group c by d(c) into g
                select g;

            return (IEnumerable<T>)query;
        }

        static void Print(IEnumerable<IGrouping<bool, Course>> list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Q1 Results:");
            foreach (var g in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine(g.Key);
                Console.WriteLine("---------------");
                foreach (var c in g)
                    Console.WriteLine(c);
            }
        }

        static void Print<T>(IEnumerable<T> list)
        {
            foreach (var l in list)
                Console.WriteLine(l);
        }



    }
}
```

the output for the two Console.writeline has to be:

```
list[1].ShowGrade(0)
99
list[2].ShowGrade(3)
```

Comment: This code won't compile, there are issues with protection level i.e. `c_name` is internal to `Course` but you are trying to use object initialization but via the constructor - this won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You have a list of *courses* with students that are exposed as `s`:

```
Console.Writeline(list[1].s.ShowGrade(0));
```

You therefore need to access the `s` field of `list[x]`. However, I'd suggest you to use a *property* instead of the public field:

```
class Course
{
    internal string c_name {get; set;}
    public Student Student { get; private set; }

    public Course()
    {
        this.Student = new Student();
    }
}
```

I actually recommend you to create `Student` as **a non-inner class**. Inner classes are supposed to be used locally only.

```
class Student
{
    internal s_name {get; set;}
    internal List<int> gradesList {get; set;}
}
```

If you want to keep `Student` as an inner class, you have to **make it `public`** in order to use it outside the `Course` class.

Answer (score 1):

`list[n]` returns a `Course`, which has a `Student` property (one course can have one student?), from where you want to show the grade.

Your `Student` class needs this method:

```
public int ShowGrade(int index)
{
   return gradesList[index];
}
```

Then you can call:

```
list[n1].s.ShowGrade(n2);
```

Comment: i can't use this: list[n1].s.ShowGrade(n2);  my professor want this: list[n1].ShowGrade(n2);  directly from list.

Comment: @ShimritRevivo then you should implement the `ShowGrade()` method on the `Course` class.

Comment: @CodeCaster I already suggested this however apparently the OP isn't allowed to do that either. Based on the current implementation of `Course`/`Student` and given the constraints he has what the OP is looking to do isn't possible.

Comment: @James there appear to be some misunderstandings between student, assignment and instructor. OP's code and restrictions don't make any sense and I wish him the bests of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your code definitely needs to be revised as there are issues i.e.

```
new Course ("C#", s.s_name = "Bob", s.gradesList = new List<int>(){100, 99, 85})
```

won't compile, it seems like you are getting confused with passing constructor parameters & [object initialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397680.aspx).

> I can't use constructors

You can only use object initialization to some extent, for example, given `c_name` is public you could do:

```
var course = new Course()
{
    c_name = "C#"
}
```

However, you can't do:

```
var course = new Course()
{
    s.gradeList = ...
}
```

You just need to manually set this

```
var course = new Course()
{
    c_name = "C#"
};
course.s.gradeList = new List<int>() { ... }
```

<strike>To answer your question though, I would use a bit of encapsulation here and expose a `ShowGrade` method in your `Course` class which would give you the code you want i.e.</strike>

```
Console.Writeline(list[1].ShowGrade(0));
```

Internally, `Course` would just delegate the call onto the student instance e.g.

```
public int ShowGrade(int grade)
{
    return s.ShowGrade(grade);
}
```

Just realised you said you can't add `ShowGrade` to the `Course` class, in that case you just need to access the `Student` property from the `Course` i.e.

```
 list[0].s.ShowGrade(0);
```

---

The penny just dropped on this one, you need to have the code like:

```
list[0].ShowGrade(0);
```

but can't modify the `Course` class - the only alternative is to use an **extension method** e.g.

```
public static class CourseExt
{
    public static int ShowGrade(this Course course, int grade)
    {
        return course.s.ShowGrade(grade);
    }
}
...
Console.WriteLine(list[0].ShowGrade(0));
```

Comment: my professor doesn't want it to be on the Course class.. thats the constraint on this

Comment: @ShimritRevivo ah sorry missed that

Comment: he also want it to be as i wrote: list[0].ShowGrade(0);  that's what i don't understand.... how can i do that ?

Comment: it's working!!!!! only my return is:  return course.s[grade];  i worked with indexer. thank you!

Comment: Ah no worries, also, tell your professor that this is **not** a great of example of how to use extension methods. They should be used to *extend* existing types without having to derive from them to add functionality - you have full control over the source here so an extension method is unnecessary.

Comment: yes i know, he just wants us to use it i guess.. not very clever :-)

Comment: I have another new question about this assignment, something simple i guess.. i put it in new Quest. I will glad if you can see it and help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you asked for:

```
class Course
{
    internal string CourseName { get; set; }
    public Student s { get; set; }

    public class Student
    {
        internal string StudentName { get; set; }
        internal IEnumerable<int> GradesList { get; set; }

        public int ShowGrade(int index)
        {
            if (GradesList == null)
                throw new NullReferenceException();
            return GradesList.ElementAt<int>(index);
        }
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Course> list = new List<Course>()
    {
        new Course () { CourseName = "C#", 
            s =  new Course.Student() { StudentName = "Bob", 
                                                                            GradesList = new List<int>() { 100, 99, 85 }}},  
        new Course () { CourseName = "Java", 
            s =  new Course.Student() { StudentName = "Bobi", 
                                                                            GradesList = new List<int>(){ 99, 90, 88 }}},
        new Course (){ CourseName = "C", 
            s = new Course.Student() { StudentName = "Roni", 
                                                                            GradesList = new List<int>()}},
        new Course (){ CourseName = "SQL", 
            s = new Course.Student() { StudentName = "Sean", 
                                                                            GradesList = new List<int>(){ 75, 62, 55 }}}
    };
        Console.WriteLine(list[0].s.ShowGrade(1));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP says they can't use constructors (which I assume means custom constructors).

Comment: In the sample code the Courses are created using a constructor, you can't have an type without a constructor in C#. Even if you don't declare it, you still get the default one, same for static types.

Comment: Yep exactly - which is why I wrote "*which I assume means custom constructors*".

Comment: i can use the default constructor, i don't have any other choice.. i just can't use costumed constructors/ overloaded constructors.

Comment: Also, all code i wrote in the Main method is just as my professor wants it to look like.. i have a problem of calling the ShowGrade as he want and not put it in the Course class.. list[1].ShowGrade(0)

Comment: @StefanSzakal I wanted to put the ShowGrade in Course class but my professor doesn't want it to be there..  I thought about it and I think i need to use extensions and indexers.. what do you think ?

Comment: @James maybe Extensions and indexers ... ?